# How can I recover folder removed from /tmp after reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, file-recovery

I just put web services folder into `/tmp` for some tests.  After I forgot that, and rebooted the server and now my service folder is gone. So, I tried r-studio for recovery but I have got nothing back.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

---

When I use PhotoRec, I could not recover the service folder. Why I can not recover deleted file from 2 days ago? I have recovered files that are one year old.

Comment: With all data recovery, you have the problem that the data is lost if it's overwritten. This might be the case for `/tmp` under heavy usage.

Comment: Is `/tmp` not a tmpfs on your system? `df -T` In that case recovery tools wouldn't help as they can only recover what was written to disk once, nothing that was on a RAM filesystem only.